# Getting Error : "Invalid date: [19/8/2013]. The row will be skipped in informatica

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, informatica-powercenter

We have a source as a flat file which consists of a date column in format 19/08/2013.
We have a target in oracle table which consists of a date column in format 11-AUG-13.
When we are trying to pass the source column value in target using expression TO_DATE AND
TO_CHAR like

```
**source column is A ---> Source column
v1=TO_CHAR(A)
O1(output column)=TO_DATE(V1,'DD-MON-YY') we are getting the below error.

Invalid date: [19/8/2013]. The row will be skipped.**
```

Can anyone please help where I'm going wrong.

Thank you

Comment: All the data type is of date types

Comment: Oracle date columns don't have any human-readable format - DD-MON-YY is just how your client displays it to you. If you're going to use `to_date()` then give it the format that matches the string - `TO_DATE(V1, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`. The `to_char()` looks odd though, not sure what that is doing. You might just want `TO_DATE(A, 'DD/MM/YYYY')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the str to date properly and then infa will load them.
Change the mapping like this -

1. Change data type in source to a string. read data as string.
2. Then use your expressions but change the to_date function like below.

```
v1(var column, data type string)=A
O1(output column, data type date)=IIF(IS_DATE(V1,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE(V1,DD/MM/YYYY'),null)
```

`IS_DATE` - will check if the data is a date or not, if yes then only it will try to convert to a proper date else put null.
3. Then connect O1 column to a date type in oracle target.

This will make sure all data are loaded and none skipped.